# Show by a counter example that a $(i,j)\gamma$-$T_1$ bitopological space may not be a $(i,j)\gamma$-$T_2$ bitopological space.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, separation-axioms

A bitopological space $(X, \tau_i, \tau_j)$ is said to be a $(i, j)\gamma$
-$T_1$ space iff for each pair of distinct points $x$ and $y$ in $X$, there exists $ij$-$\gamma$-open sets $G$ and $H$ containing $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $y \notin G$ and $x \notin H$.

The space is called a $(i, j)\gamma$-$T_2$ space iff for each pair of distinct points $x$ and $y$, there exist disjoint $ij$-$\gamma$-open sets $G$ and $H$ in $X$
such that $x \in G, y \notin G$ and $y \in H, x \notin H$.

For more the definition of $ij$-$\gamma$-open set is given below:

A set $A$ is said to be a $ij$-$\gamma$-open set if intersection
of $A$ with each $ij$-preopen sets gives a $ij$-preopen set.

A set $A$ is said to be a $ij$-preopen set if $A \subseteq \tau_i$-$int(\tau_j$-$cl(A))$.

Comment: You have several questions with an imperative statement in the title, and nothing in the text of the post other than some definitions. Questions which simply demand that we show you something are frowned upon.  I suggest that you take a look at this post: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, the text of your post should have an actual mathematical question, it should have some motivation, and it should have some evidence of what you have tried in your attempts to resove the question.

Comment: I tried with two point and three points sets. Every time I am taking a $(i,j)\gamma$-$T_1$ space, the collection of all $ij$-$\gamma$-open sets is containing disjoint $\gamma$-open sets for any two distinct points. Thus it is becoming a $(i,j)\gamma$-$T_2$ space.